# Rollback a GCP Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We've got a flummoxing problem with Google Cloud Platform. On one of our projects, a bunch of Cloud Functions and service accounts were deleted. Does anyone know if there's a GCP command/other easy way to roll back to a certain date/time all the projects' settings?

Currently waiting on GCP support, but it's taking a while.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such feature, I don't think you can bring back a service account or cloud function, but you can always ask GCP support for that.

If they don't provide a solution then you have to manually re-deploy the cloud functions and re-create the service accounts (and re-configure the resources that uses them).

If you are confused about what happened in your project remember that you can use GCP activity log in order to use IAM to constraint the culprit and avoid the problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your project deleted (the whole project), then you have up to 30 days to "undelete" it and have it back to the state it was before deletion. However, there is no way to bring back the project to a previous state, that is, there is no version control for projects.